# Workstation as Master [Turtlebot]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hi,
I am trying to run the workstation as master with one turtlebot. After booting up the turtlebot as a non master I launch the turtlebot node by running minimal.launch. The node launches fine but I get the attached errors on the turtlebot commandline.
Inspite of these errors, the turtlebot runs fine but when I subscribe to the odometry data on the workstation I noticed that the odometry gets lost for long periods of time. The "rostopic hz /odom" shows "no new messages" on the workstation and there is an error ("device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)") displayed on the turtlebot commandline.**

Here is the error I get on the turtlebot commandline:

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1371589364.129064] Failed to contact device with error: [device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1371589370.596000] Failed to contact device with error: [device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1371589377.007524] Failed to contact device with error: [device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1371589383.468197] Failed to contact device with error: [[Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.

**Thank you,**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65437/workstation-as-master-%5Bturtlebot%5D/) by [satk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5181/satk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This usually means your turtlebot battery needs to be charged. Or that the connection from turtlebot to the laptop is loose.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [satk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5181/satk/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thank you for your reply. I do not get these errors when turtlebot is the master. So, I don't think that the robot is not charged or the connection is loose.